# Create bar chart on top of totals with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

To avoid making a pie chart I want to create a barchart. I do however want to show the total for each catagory. Here's my dataset created with `dput()` function:

```
df <- structure(list(Status = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Compromise", 
"Launched", "Not yet rated", "Promise broken", "Promise kept", 
"Stuck"), class = "factor"), n = c(15L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 21L), 
    total = c("60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60")), .Names = c("Status", 
"n", "total"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here's my ggplot2 code:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Status, y = n, fill = Status)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            hjust = 2,
            colour = "white",
            fontface = "bold",
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(order)) +
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "null")
```

And here's an example from pew research center (obviously with totally different data) to get an idea of what I try to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe how your code falls short of your desired output so I don't have to run your code to see your problem?

Comment: The code just shows a bar chart. I want to know how I create the light grey bars to show totals.

Comment: Make another column of (100-percentage) and stack the bar chart?

Comment: or make another layer of bars all to 100 and position it underneath (before)

Comment: You can add another layer for total using `geom_col`. Maybe something like `geom_col(aes(y=as.numeric(total)), color="gray", alpha=0.3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the `total`, you just need to convert it to numeric and add another `geom_col` layer first.

```
df$total = as.numeric(as.character(df$total))

  ggplot(df, aes(x = Status, y = n, fill = Status)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = total), fill = "grey90") +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            hjust = 2,
            colour = "white",
            fontface = "bold",
            size = 3) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(order)) +
    scale_fill_tableau() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "null")
```